# Aligning IMG and text in span with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a button with an image in it by using a span.
The following works but the problem is that the text is vertically middle aligned, but the save button img is'nt. I need all the content to be verticall aligned in the middle. What is wrong with my code?

```
.ButtonSPAN{
display:inline-block;
color: white;
background-color:#00537B;
border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
height: 25px;

padding:3px;
vertical-align:middle;
font-weight: bold;
}
.ButtonSPAN:hover{
color: #F0E68C;
cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;  
}

<span class="ButtonSPAN"><img src="/common/images/save.png" onclick="Save()">&nbsp;Save</span>
```

Comment: you know you can put images in buttons too? `<button class="ButtonSPAN" onclick="Save()"><img src="/common/images/save.png">&nbsp;Save</button>` will work just fine.

Comment: save.png dimensions ?

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey: No, didn't know that :)
@ AndreaLigios: it's 16*16 pixels

Comment: Have a look at how Twitter Bootstrap code up their buttons with images: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Updated]** Wrap your "Save" in a `span`, and add to your css

```
.ButtonSPAN{
    line-height:25px;
}

.ButtonSPAN *{
    vertical-align:middle; //Align everything nested in .ButtonSPAN to the middle
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/zSDtv/4/)

Comment: By doing this nothing is in the middle anymore, it all sticks to the top

Comment: This works almost. The text is abount 2 pixels more to the top than the text. How to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/csSef/), illustrating the different values available for `vertical-align`. Your example CSS shows you applying `inline-block` to the parent (the `.ButtonSPAN`), which won't help with aligning the contents within.

The simplest way to achieve what you're after is to wrap your text in a separate `span` and then use this:

```
<button><img src="http://placehold.it/36x36"> <span>Middle</span></button>

button {
    color: white;
    background-color:#00537B;
    border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
    padding: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

img, span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here's a screenshot from the above jsFiddle. I've made the image slightly larger and given the `span` a `background-color` to better illustrate the variants:

[image: vertical-align examples]

Answer (score 0):

There are some thinks that might work.
My first option would be to put image as `background:url(image_path)` to span and give height, width and margin to align it properly. You can put multiple backgrounds and just add a anchor on where you want your click to be, or make all your span clickable.
Second option would be to align that image veriticaly with `vertical-align:middle`.
Third is to edit that image to let a transparent space above the image.

Hope something of this will help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here:

you can apply the image as a background image to your span:

```
.ButtonSPAN{
    background:#00537B url(/common/images/save.png) 3px center no-repeat;
}
```

you would have to put your `onClick="save()"` to your `span` element.

[Background-image property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

OR, provided you know the height of the image, this should work:

(I am assuming an image height of 16px)

```
.ButtonSPAN{
    position:relative;
}
.ButtonSPAN img{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-8px;
}
```

Or, alternatively, look at this [page](http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html)

P.S. It is good practice to start your class names with a lowercase letter.

Comment: The image he is using is 16x16 pixels. It is not going to be used as a background image.

Comment: Why not? It seems like the best option to me.

Answer (score 0):

As you are keeping both the text and the image in a single `span` element, you need to work around as shown in the below fiddle:

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ozodig/3/edit)**

Here I added `marign-bottom:-3px` to make it look like in middle with the text.

```
.ButtonSPAN img{  
   margin-bottom:-3px;  /* fix until the img comes to mid */
   width:16px;height:16px; /* giving fixed widths for demo */
}
```

I also removed `vertical-align` from the `.ButtonSPAN` class and added `line-height` equal to height's value instead.